# Pointing Conda R to already-installed version of R

Tags: python, r, bash, conda, spyder

My problem has to do with the fact that RStudio and Conda are pointing to different versions of R.  My R and RStudio were installed independent of Anaconda, and everything is working great.

In my ~/.bash_profile, RStudio points to

```
alias R='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R'
alias r='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R'
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R:$PATH
launchctl setenv RSTUDIO_WHICH_R $RSTUDIO_WHICH_R
```

Calling R on Terminal gives me R version 3.5.3, which is what RStudio is using.
However, conda is using R version 3.5.1, and 3.5.3 is not available on conda:

```
conda search
```

says 3.5.3 is not an option.  Making changes to my .bash_profile (and sourcing it) has not changed what conda reads, which is

```
/Users/mjk/opt/anaconda3/bin/r
```

The whole reason I'm using Anaconda is that I'm programming in Python, using Spyder, and I want to make some calls to some of my R scripts, and these are unfortunately R-version-dependent.

What I'd really like to do is simply point conda to the already installed version of R I have (/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R), and not be dependent on it installing its own version.

Is there a way to do this?

Or am I better off using a stand-alone version of Spyder outside of Anaconda?

Thank you!

Comment: why not uninstall the conda installed R version?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) For Spyder to take the PATH modification you added to your `~/.bash_profile`, you need to start it from Terminal.app. How are you starting it at the moment?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I am starting Spyder from Anaconda-Navigator.  It's not even visible in my Apps unless I launch Anaconda-Navigator.  I'm going to try to install the stand-alone Spyder app and launch from the Terminal.app.